# How to estimate Lake area and volume in Mathematica?

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, functions, mathematical-optimization, image-processing, regions

I have a satellite image of the lake and I want to estimate its area and volume.

Actual volume:1.49*10e8 m^3

Actual Area:36.9 km^2

I did the following command to find the volume, but it is not very accurate. Can someone help me make the volume more accurate and find the area?

[image]

```
img =(Image);

ListPlot3D[ImageData[GradientFilter[img, 2]], PlotRange -> All, 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

[image]

```
{h, w} = Dimensions[ImageData[img]][[;; 2]];
markers = 
  SparseArray[{Round[{h, w}/2] -> 1, {1, _} -> 1, {-1, _} -> 
     1, {_, 1} -> 1, {_, -1} -> 1}, {h, w}];

segmentation = 
 DeleteBorderComponents[
  Image[WatershedComponents[GradientFilter[img, 2], Image[markers]]]]
components = 
  ComponentMeasurements[
   segmentation, {"Area", "Centroid", "Orientation"}];
```

[image]

```
{area, centroid, orientation} = 
 SortBy[components[[All, 2]], First][[-1]]
direction = {Cos[orientation], Sin[orientation]};

Show[segmentation, 
 Graphics[{Red, 
   Line[{centroid + w*direction, centroid - w*direction}]}]]
```

[image]

```
xs = Array[#2 - 1. &, {h, w}];
ys = Array[N[h - #1] &, {h, w}];

distCenterAxis = 
  Abs[direction . {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}} . ({xs, ys} - centroid)];

volume = distCenterAxis*\[Pi];

Total[volume*ImageData[Binarize[segmentation]], 2]
```

out put is 2.38782*10^7

Comment: Clarifying question: how are you getting depth for calculating the volume of the lake?

Comment: Calculated from the solid volume of rotation of each pixel And we merge this for the split pixels.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how this is a valid way to estimate the depth of the lake at each position. If I am understanding correctly, you are rotating the pixels around the longest axis of the lake? So the "depth" at each position is dependent on how far the pixel is from the longest axis, but I don't actually understand how this would correlate at all with the actual depth of the lake at each position. I would think the only way to estimate lake volume would be to have bathymetry data on it.

Comment: Yes, this method is obtained by rotating pixels, Is it possible to find the area and volume by obtaining the polygon shape of the lake and having the depth?

Comment: Do you have the depth data at each pixel point in the image? It kind of looks like depth is encoded by color in this image but I could be wrong about that, and I don't know what the color-depth function looks like if this is the case. 

But If you do have depth data at each pixel, just first calculate the area of each pixel by calculating the pixel length of the 3 km bar in the image, sum all the depths, and multiply them by the pixel area

[Here's an example nb](https://www.wolframcloud.com/env/b3c7edb2-fbd8-4472-9d14-ee61594875d5)

Comment: Thank you very much for your efforts, But i don't have the depth data at each pixel point, do you think it is possible to use the pixelvalues ​​or imagevalue commands to find the depth of each pixel?

Comment: You would have to know the function and depth. If this is not known, then I can't see a way to get depth from the information in this image.

Comment: ^sorry I meant to say **color as a function of depth** not **the function and depth**

Comment: I think if have bathymetry data, can calcute volume

Comment: Yes you can. If you have it can you add it to the question?